# How does install() behave when NULL is stored as a name definition?

Tags: c, linked-list, hashtable, lookup-tables

Trying to understand the code for an implementation of hash search as discussed in K&R C programming book (page 143-145).

Consider a `#define` statement

```
#define STATE 1
```

The aim is that we should store the name and its replacement text in a table. We create an array `hashtab` having pointers to linked lists. Each pointer refers to a linked list which has a name and its replacement text in each of its nodes (also with a link node, of course). If there are no names with a certain hash value, the array element at that index is `NULL`. For a linked list pointed to by a pointer from `hashtab` array, all nodes have names with common hash value.

Following are the function and struct definitions.

Here is the `struct nlist`. It is used to create a node which would record the name and replacement text. The node will be added in front of the already existing linked list for that hash value.

```
struct nlist { /* table entry: */
    struct nlist *next; /* next entry in chain */
    char *name; /* defined name */
    char *defn; /* replacement text */
};
```

Here is the code for the `lookup()` function. It searches for the string in the table and returns a pointer to the place where it was found, or `NULL` if the string is not present.

```
/* lookup: look for s in hashtab */
    struct nlist *lookup(char *s)
    {
    struct nlist *np;
    for (np = hashtab[hash(s)]; np != NULL; np = np->next)
        if (strcmp(s, np->name) == 0)
            return np; /* found */
    return NULL; /* not found */
}
```

The `strdup()` function which makes a duplicate of a string `src`. Error handling, for example when `malloc()` returns `NULL`, is left to the caller.

```
char *strdup(const char *src) {
    char *p = (char *) malloc(strlen (src) + 1);  // Space for length plus '\0'
    if (p != NULL) strcpy(p, src);
    return p;                            
}
```

My questions mainly concern the following `install()` function which records a name and replacement text in the front of the already existing linked list for that hash value.

```c
/* install: put (name, defn) in hashtab */
struct nlist *install(char *name, char *defn)
{
    struct nlist *np;
    unsigned hashval;
    if ((np = lookup(name)) == NULL) { /* not found */
        np = (struct nlist *) malloc(sizeof(*np));
        if (np == NULL || (np->name = strdup(name)) == NULL)
            return NULL;
        hashval = hash(name);
        np->next = hashtab[hashval];
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
    } else /* already there */
        free((void *) np->defn); /*free previous defn */
    if ((np->defn = strdup(defn)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return np;
}
```

I have not written the `hash()` function here.

What is the significance of its return value to the `main()`?
One more related question:
The last if condition may assign `NULL` to `np->defn` (and also returns it). How will this assignment of `NULL` be useful to the user of `install()` since the first item in the list of names (having such hash values) would contain `NULL` in the defn? Are we allowing a name to have `NULL` as its definition and ignoring the reason why `NULL` was assigned to its `defn` field?

Comment: There are a few problems with the `install` function, including memory leaks and possible incomplete nodes in the `hashtab[hashval]` list.

Comment: When `install()` function starts returning `NULL`s you've bigger fish to fry, shortage of memory.

Comment: So, when `install()` returns `NULL`  it simply means that we are short of memory otherwise it is `np`. But we just care about it not being `NULL`. Even if we know that now the name has the unwanted `NULL` stored in its node (is this the 'incomplete node' @Someprogrammerdude talks about?), now we should address shortage of memory and then try replacing its `defn` later. May be I have very silly question here, but can we deliberately store `NULL` as the replacement text!?